# Identify Conservative Vector Fields

Tags: multivariable-calculus

[image]

I have no idea where to begin. How do I approach such a problem?

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: if a vector field is conservative, then its curl is 0. Visually, what does it mean to have curl = 0?

Comment: @ImHereSometimes curl = 0 means regardless of which point you choose, the object you place at the point will not rotate? Is that right?

Comment: Essentially, yes. So you know exactly one vector field is conservative; it should then be the one that has some rotation going on (ie. curl is non-zero).

Comment: @ImHereSometimes Thank you for your comment. Just to clarify, this rotation MUST be about the origin to be considered curl, correct?

Comment: The best way to think about it is if you placed a paddlewheel at some point, if the wheel will spin (ie. the field represents fluid flow) then there is non-zero curl. It's not really as cut and dry as a rotation about the origin. See http://www2.sjs.org/raulston/mvc.10/topic.6.lab.1.htm

Answer (score 3):

A conservative vector field $\vec f(\vec x) $  is the gradient of some scalar field ,

$$\vec f(\vec x) =\vec \nabla V(\vec x)$$ so the value of all path integrals depend only on the endpoints 
$$ \int_\vec {x_0}^\vec {x_1} \vec f \cdot d\vec s = V(\vec {x_1}) - V(\vec {x_0})$$
In particular,  the path integral around any closed curve is zero

$$\oint \vec f \cdot d\vec s =0 $$

Consider taking path integrals counterclockwise around the path defined by the frame of each of your graphs, for one of the three you can clearly see that the path integral will be non-zero and positive.